# What does it mean to be a.e. finite real function to converge in measure?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I am currently trying to understand the concept of convergence of a series of function in measure, but I don't really understand what it means when a series of function fn

For example, 
https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/5-2.pdf
has its definition stating

The series of a.e. finite function {$f_n$} converges in measure to a.e. finite real valued function $f$ if

$$
\lim_n m({x: \vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert >\epsilon})=0
$$
for all $\epsilon$>0 and m is a measure.

However, how can we define $\vert f(x)-f_n(x)\vert$ when both $f(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ are not finite?
The definition says that a.e. finite so it doesn't exclude the function to be extended real function.
I see this kind of definition in several textbook such as Halmos's Measure Theory.

Does the definition implicitly suggesting the above equation to hold a.e.?

Answer (score 1):

There exists sets $E,E_1,E_2,...$ of measure $0$ such that $f_n(x)$ is finite if $x \notin E_n$ and $f(x)$ is finite if $x \notin E$. Let $A=E\cup E_1\cup E_2\cup...$. Then $A$ has measure $0$ and all the functions $f,f_1,f_2..$ are finite if $x \notin A$. We can interpret $m(x: |f(x)-f_n(x)| >\epsilon)$ as $m(x\notin A: |f(x)-f_n(x)| >\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In this case, is $x \notin E$ necessary condition?
It seems like if {$f_n$} converges to $f$ then $E$ necessary has measure zero.

Comment: In the definition you quoted it is assumed that you are ignoring the points where one of the fuctions has value $\pm \infty$. My argument shows that this only excludes a set of measure $0$. @sharkbear

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. So the definition implicitly assumes we are ignoring the points with nonfinite values?
I don't think it's explicitly stated as we can still define $\vert f(x)-f_n(x) \vert$ if one is finite.